# Puzzle about two workers and a cart. Usage lock and conditions doesn't work

Tags: java, multithreading, conditional-statements, locks

When using **synchronized** block or method, we synchronized by mutable object. But I don't understand how to use **Locks with Conditions** from j.u.c.. I'm trying to solve puzzle with two workers and a cart with lock and conditions. When first worker add weight to the cart - second wait. When cart is full, than first worker wait and second releases the cart. 
 I create two threads for each worker and use one cart. But in reality only one thread performs (worker, that add weight) until cart is full. Than program blocks. What I'm doing wrong and what I misunderstand? 
That's my implementation of this puzzle.

```
package puzzles.workers;

public enum WorkerType {
    ADDER, REDUCER;
}
```

Cart class

```
package puzzles.workers;
public class Cart {
private static final int INITIAL_CAPACITY = 10;
private static final int INITIAL_WEIGHT = 0;

private int capacity;
private int weight;



public Cart() {
    this(INITIAL_CAPACITY);
}

public Cart(int capacity) {
    this.capacity = capacity;
    weight = INITIAL_WEIGHT;
}

public void addWeight() {
    weight++;
}

public void reduceWeight() {
    weight--;
}

public int getCapacity() {
    return capacity;
}

public int getWeight() {
    return weight;
}
}
```

Worker class.

```
package puzzles.workers;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;


public class WorkerWithLock implements Runnable {
    private final Cart cart;
    private WorkerType workerType;
    final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    final Condition whenEmpty = lock.newCondition();
    final Condition whenFull = lock.newCondition();

    public WorkerWithLock(Cart cart, WorkerType workerType) {
        this.cart = cart;
        this.workerType = workerType;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            if (workerType == WorkerType.ADDER) {
                try {
                    addWeight();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            } else {
                try {
                    reduceWeight();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void addWeight() throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            while (cart.getWeight() == (cart.getCapacity() - 1)) {
                whenFull.await();
            }
            cart.addWeight();
            System.out.println("++ weight is: " + cart.getWeight());
            whenEmpty.signalAll();
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void reduceWeight() throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            while (cart.getWeight() == 0) {
                whenEmpty.await();
            }
            cart.reduceWeight();
            System.out.println("-- weight is: " + cart.getWeight());
            whenFull.signalAll();
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Cart cart = new Cart(5);
    WorkerWithLock adder = new WorkerWithLock(cart, WorkerType.ADDER);
    WorkerWithLock reducer = new WorkerWithLock(cart, WorkerType.REDUCER);

    new Thread(reducer).start();
    new Thread(adder).start();

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a kind of a **race condition**
That is because both threads are waiting.
One in `addWeight`and one in `reduceWeight`.
First the reducer stops, if weight is 0. At this time, the adder is may be not already started.
Than the adder stops, if weight = cpacity - 1

Now, both are waiting for an interrupt().

EDIT1. See my comments in the code

```
public void addWeight() throws InterruptedException {
    lock.lock();
    try {
        while (cart.getWeight() == (cart.getCapacity() - 1)) {
            whenFull.await();  //<--   ADDER waits here 
        }
        cart.addWeight();
        System.out.println("++ weight is: " + cart.getWeight());
        whenEmpty.signalAll(); //<-- Never called since both are waiting
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}

public void reduceWeight() throws InterruptedException {
    lock.lock();
    try {
        while (cart.getWeight() == 0) {
            whenEmpty.await(); //<-- REDUCER waits here
        }
        cart.reduceWeight();
        System.out.println("-- weight is: " + cart.getWeight());
        whenFull.signalAll(); //<-- Never called since both are waiting
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

EDIT2: Ok, now I understand the behaviour.
Your code is designed to synchronize ONE object for multiple threads, but your are using TWO objects.
Every of your both `WorkerWithLock` Objects has its own Lock and Condition objects. So calls of lock.lock() and whenFull.signalAll() in object ADDER does not effect Object REDUCER.

Your code will work if you make the lock and condition variables static, so that both objects are working with the same lock and the same condition

```
final static Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
final static Condition whenEmpty = lock.newCondition();
final static Condition whenFull = lock.newCondition();
```

Sometimes multithreading is hard :)

Comment: Aha, but why methods signalAll() doesn't interrupt waiting?

Comment: That is because signalAll is never called since both waits! See edits in a few minutes.

Comment: I saw this example https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html and trying use the same approach with await() and signal/signalAll()

Comment: Thank you a lot especially for EDIT2. It helps me to understand!